# Is there a way to get react-redux store value only when function is called?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have redux state called `timer` and it has state property called `remainingTime` (every second this property will be updated).

I can use `mapStateToProps` or `useSelector` to get current `remainingTime` and pass it to the component by `props`. But in that case my react component re-renders each second because `remainingTime` is updating every second. I think this will cause performance issues.

Is there a way to get store value `timer.remainingTime` only when function is called by the component (when a button clicked) ? (without re-rendering the component)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mapStateToProps` or `useSelector` to get a value that changes every second, will make your component *react* to that change (pun intended) every second, and hence, re-render every second.

However, if your component does not re-render, then, the `remainingTime` value will not update either, so I guess this is not what you want. (otherwise you could just remove that value from your props if you don't need it...)

What you can improve, though, is where you get that value.

Let's say you have a big component and then in the rendered markup, a small area where you display that value:

```
function BigComponent() {
  const { remainingTime } = useSelector(state => state.timer)
  // Heavy component logic that you cannot optimize or memoize
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {/* lots of things heavy to re-render */}
      <div>{remainingTime} seconds</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In this case, you could optimize by raising your state closer to where it is displayed:

```
function RemainingTime() {
  const { remainingTime } = useSelector(state => state.timer)
  return <div>{remainingTime} seconds</div>
}

function BigComponent() {
  // Heavy component logic that you cannot optimize or memoize
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {/* lots of things heavy to re-render */}
      <RemainingTime />
    </div>
  )
}
```

That way, only `RemainingTime` small component re-renders, but not the rest.

Not sure if it applies to your use case, but it is a typical performance optimization technique.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes I tried this way as well. But I got this error `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`cause I'm using a hook inside a function. Also I have two components, one to show the updating remaining time and other one for get the current remaining time value.

Comment: Well then you can use the hook in the body of the component? or refactor to avoid those issues / wrong component architecture?

Comment: If I use the hook in the body of the component , re-rendering is happening every second for that particular component.

Comment: Ok, finally this method worked for me.```import store from '../../../../Redux/store'; const state = store.getState();const timer = state.timer;```